# Fractional Units in Revit but Decimal Units in BIM 360 and Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

[BIM 360 vs Revit units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwhNS.png)

I'm getting this issue where in BIM 360 and the Forge Viewer I'm getting my units as decimals (and decimals rounded wrong too) when in Revit it's in fractional feet and inches. I checked that the project units are in fractional feet and inches as well, but it doesn't transfer over to BIM 360 and Forge.

How can I force Forge and BIM 360 to show fractional feet and inches?

Answer (score 0):

You actually can set the Display Units within Forge Viewer, go to **Settings->Configuration->Display Units**, change to Feet and **fractional inches**.--

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to keep these settings remembered in the viewer? So far I have to set up the Display Units to be feet and fractional inches everytime I open up a project. By default it still sets it to decimal feet and when other people open up the project it also starts off in decimal feet for them

Comment: I think you may need to create an extension to setup the unit. This extension should be loaded while your viewer started..